# How do i do vlookup better in excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have done excel Vlookup many years back and i want to learn it back again. I have watched some youtube videos and i am still not that clear.

I have 2 excel files

```
Excel A:
Datetime           weight
1/1/2011 16:00:00  100
1/1/2011 16:00:00  30
2/1/2011 16:30:00  78
2/1/2011 16:30:00  557


Excel B:
Datetime           weight
1-1-2011 16:00:00  30
2-1-2011 16:30:00  557
```

I am expecting to have some value that shows which record is able to lookup so that i can remove those that are not needed in Excel A later.

What is the correct way?

In Excel A Cell D, input below:

```
=vlookup($A1,ExcelB A2:B3,2,false)
```

(function above might not work properly as i type it out here by myself, not copied from excel)

I do not get any value to indicate whether it can be lookup or not. It is only giving me #N/A

BTW, must the datetime be exactly the same in excel A and B? i noticed the datetime format is different in this 2 files.

Comment: Datetime format shouldnt be the same. If both are recognized as a date then excel has its own corresponding value for exactly that date and time. e.g. "01-01-2019" = 43466 in excel datetime. However when using `vlookup()` with the last parameter as false it will only find an exact match. In the case of datetime this means down to the last second. This can be why you're experiencing problems.

Comment: your formula returns an error, because your dates are formatted differently. Use - or / in both files

Comment: _"..vlookup better in excel?.."_ so.. specifically..  what is wrong (and right) with the current method.. ?

Comment: Guys. I jsut realised that Excel A is having datetime format while excel B is a character datetime......should i convert both into the same exact data type and value first?

Comment: yes, that might work and use a 'MATCH' formula to see if you can find the value in the first place, then use the VLOOKUP formula to return a corresponding value as you need.